# Extracting multiline content from flow file content

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I am importing data from MySQL table (for selected columns only) and putting it in HDFS. Once this is done, I want to create a table in Hive.

For this I have a `schema.sql` file which contains the CREATE TABLE statement for the entire table and I want to generate the new CREATE TABLE statement only for the columns I imported.

Something similar to what I am doing with `grep` in the below example.

[image]

I used `FetchFile` along with `ExtractText` but couldn't make it work. How can I achieve this using NiFi processors or even Expression Language if I get the overall schema into an attribute?

Or is there a better way to create table on the imported data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NiFi can generate Create table statement[s] based on the flowfile content

> **1.Creating ORC tables by using ConvertAvroToORC processor:**

- if you are converting the avro data into ORC format then storing into HDFS then ConvertAvroToORC processor adds `hive.ddl` attribute to the flowfile.
- PutHDFS processor adds `absolute.hdfs.path` attribute to the flowfile.
- We can use this **hive.ddl**, **absolute.hdfs.path** attributes and create the orc table on top of HDFS directory dynamically.

**Flow:**

```
 Pull data from source(ExecuteSQL...etc)
  -> ConvertAvroToORC //add Hive DbName,TableName in HiveTableName property value--> 
  -> PutHDFS //store the orc file into HDFS location --> 
  -> ReplaceText //Replace the flowfile content with ${hive.ddl} Location '${absolute.hdfs.path}'--> 
  -> PutHiveQL //execute the create table statement
```

Refer to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-automatically-migrate-all-tables-from-a-dat) link for more details regrads to the above flow.

> **2.Creating Avro tables by using ExtractAvroMetaData processor:**

- In NiFi once we pull data by using QueryDatabaseTable,ExecuteSQL processors the format of the data is in **AVRO**.
- We can create **Avro tables** based on **avro schema(.avsc file)** and by using **ExtractAvroMetaData** processor we can extract the schema and keep as flowfile attribute then by using this schema we can create AvroTables dynamically.

**Flow:**

```
ExecuteSQL (success)|-> PutHDFS //store data into HDFS
           (success)|-> ExtractAvroMetadata //configure Metadata Keys as avro.schema 
                     -> ReplaceText //replace flowfile content with avro.schema
                     -> PutHDFS //store the avsc file into schema directory
                     -> ReplaceText //create avro table on top of schema directory
                     -> PutHiveQL //execute the hive.ddl
```

**Example [AVRO](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe) create table statement:**

```
CREATE TABLE as_avro
  ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
  STORED as INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.url'='/path/to/the/schema/test_serializer.avsc');
```

We are going to change **path to the schema url** by using ReplaceText processor in the above flow.

Another way using **ExecuteSQL** processor get all the **create table statements** (or) **columns info from (sys.tables/INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ..etc)** from source (if source system permits) and write a script to `map the data types` into `hive appropriate types` then store them in your `desired format` in Hive.

***EDIT:***

To run `grep` command on the flowfile content we need to use **ExecuteStreamCommand** processor

***ESC Configs:***

[image]

Then feed the `output stream` relation to ExtractText Processor

***ET Configs:***

Add new property as

**content**

```
(?s)(.*)
```

[image]

Then `content attribute` is added to the flowfile, You can use that attribute and prepare create table statements.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried using Avro earlier and did it again after your answer. The column data types are not coming correct in schema. It marks almost everything as string type. Even bigint and timestamp columns are marked as string. Regarding the last approach, the schema.sql file mentioned in the question already had the column name and it's corresponding Hive data type. From that I wanted to extract only interested columns lines and then construct CREATE TABLE query with LOCATION.

Comment: @pratpor, Try with **Avro Logical Types property value to True** in ExecuteSQL..etc then check the datatypes in avro data file.

Comment: @pratpor, Please check my updated answer's **EDIT** section, describes how to extract only the required columns from the ff content.

Comment: Was just reading about `ExecuteStreamCommand`. That works. Thanks for the help. Update on using `Avro Logical Types` property, it doesn't work. It puts timestamp and bigint, bigint as string.